# SubClassing UIButton but I can't get "addTarget:action:forControlEvents:" to execute?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have subclassed UIButton to draw graphics, but the "addTarget" won't work.

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

I did not do anything with making adjustments to that method.

The Button graphics work ok on the "touches".

If I use a standard UIButton then the "addTarget" works fine.

Not sure what I am missing??

thx

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CButton : UIButton
{
    CGContextRef c;
    int myState;
}
@end
```

---

```
#import "CButton.h"

@implementation CButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    //NSLog(@"init state: %d", self.state);
    return self;
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  //  myState = 1;
    myState = !myState;
   // NSLog(@"BeginState: %d", self.state);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  //  myState = 0;
  //  NSLog(@"EndState: %d", self.state);
  //  [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code

}
@end
```

Comment: This isn't going to answer your question, but subclassing `UIButton` usually leads to disaster.  I'd try subclassing `UIControl` instead.  It's a bit more work, but you'll be happy in the long run.

Comment: Agreed, I've always been told subclassing UIButton is a bad idea.

Comment: Please show the subclass `@interface` and implementation of `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:` methods.

Comment: Why exactly is it a bad idea to subclass UIButton? Just out of curiosity, is there some documentation about negative behavior or so?

Comment: @Fuggly: It's bad because the normal initialization of a `UIButton` consists of using class methods to instantiate a button (`buttonWithType:`).  When you initialize a `UIButton` in this manner, your subclass may or may not be used to instantiate this button.  This unpredictable behavior leaves much to be desired in the way of subclassing, and perhaps just sticking with a plain old `UIControl` is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call super from your event handlers when you're all done handling events. How else will the button know of the touches to call your action?

e.g.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  //  myState = 1;
    myState = !myState;
   // NSLog(@"BeginState: %d", self.state);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; // you need this
}
```

That being said, the comments on your original post are right, subclassing UIButton can get tricky. But it looks as if you have things under control (mostly). Good luck!

Comment: I had to do super for both touchesBegan and touchesEnded...thx